# Get low stock from a C# dll database which generate million rows automatically

Tags: c#, string, object, hashtable

I have database (C#, dll) which contains only one table, generates million rows automatically.

I can only get one row at once. The table's columns are : `int ItemID, string category, string model, string Brand`).

Two items are same if they have same `category, brand, model`). I want to find out all types of items that are low in stock, where low is that  there are two or less items of that type left.

This is the code I wrote for this, but it took 2 or 3 hours to execute, it is not give me correct results. How can I solve this?

```
   public DataTable getLowStock()
   {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       object[,] arr=new object[1000000,4];
       int  index=0;
       int rows;
       rows = db.NumRows;
       int[] IdArray;
       IdArray = db.GetItemIDList(0, rows - 1);

       string Category, Brand, Model, Condition, Location, Notes;
       DateTime ReceivedDate, LastUpdated;
       int Weight;
       double PurchasePrice, SellingPrice;

       for (int a = 0; a < IdArray.Length; a++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(a);

           db.GetItemRecord(IdArray[a], out Category, out Brand, out Model,
                            out ReceivedDate, out Weight, out Condition, out Location,
                            out PurchasePrice, out SellingPrice, out Notes, out LastUpdated);

           if (a == 0)
           {
               arr[0, 0] = Category;
               arr[0, 1] = Brand;
               arr[0, 2] = Model;
               arr[0, 3] =  1;
               index++;

           }
           else
           {

               for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
               {

                   if ( ( arr[i,2].ToString()==Model)&& (arr[i,1].ToString()==Brand) &&   (arr[i,0].ToString()==Category ) )
                   {

                       arr[i, 3] = (Int32)arr[i, 3] + 1;
                   }
               }

               arr[index,0]=Category;
               arr[index,1]=Brand;
               arr[index,2]=Model;
               arr[index, 3] = 1;

               index++;
           }

       }

        dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));    
        dt.Columns.Add("Model", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Brand", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("count", typeof(int));   

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
           Console.WriteLine("i="+i);

       if((int)arr[i,3]<3){
           dt.Rows.Add(arr[i,0].ToString(),arr[i,2].ToString(),arr[i,1].ToString(),(int)arr[i,3]);
       }
       }
       return dt;
   }
```

Comment: `(C#, dll)` is not a real database - what are you using? Presumably SQL Server - then the question is: **why** do you load all the data onto your client to detect duplicates and/or low stock? This is what a database is for - do it **on the (SQL) Server**!

Comment: i can do this easily with queries ,but this is an assignment.they have restricted the use of LINQ ,binding and datasources.

Comment: I highly doubt you'll be able to significantly speed up your processing then.... there's no "magic" way to do this fast - if you need to do this on the client - it just takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the best way to do this is with an actual database? Then you can do the query in SQL, which will execute about 1000 times faster than querying an in-memory datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fetching the whole table I suggest you execute a sql aggregation and fetch only the aggregates:

```
SELECT category, model, brand, COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY category, model, brand
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Then, your code is very slow for several reasons, but the main one is that it is quadratic.
So 1 million squared makes one thousand billion operations, which is quite slow.

If you must do the aggregation yourself you have to use a fitting container, like a set or a hash table, not an array. This way you will perform in O(n) (with a good hash table)  or O(n log n) ( with a set), instead of 0(n^2).

Comment: @marc_s,@OlivierS thank you very much,but with a hash table i can only add two pairs(value and the key).i have tried this with a hash table by concating 3 string values ,but it too takes long time,after the operation i cant re order the 3 fields too.

Comment: your key should be something like the `String.Concat(Category,'_',Model,'_',Brand)` , and the value the number of times you find this key. Then you output the keys where values >= 2. Obviously if your table has 1million rows it might be quite long to fetch them.